# Hibernate self foreign key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

I'd like to have a Category object where there are parent categories with children categories.

I'm trying to map it with Hibernate. I found no more than 2 examples of what I mean on the Internet so I ask the question.

Table :

- category_id : int
- category_label : varchar
- category_description
- category_parent : int + foreign key (category_id)

What I did :

```
public class Category implements Serializable {

@Id@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int category_id;
private String category_label;
private String category_description;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="category_id")
private Category category_parent;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="category_parent")
private List<Category> category_children;

// Getters and setters

}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Any idea of what? Except for the missing space betwen your annotations and for the lack of respect of Java naming conventions, the code is fine. Why don't you test it?